# Vertical space after new paragraph in enumerate enviroment

Tags: formatting, enumitem

Why is there vertical space here? and how can I remove it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Imported packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, isbn=false, doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}

% Lemma & Example commands
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}

% Single letter sets
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

% New operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}

% Indentation Settings
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent}

\title{Homework 2 - MATH 4001}
\author{Clyde Kertzer}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    First line.

    Why is there vertical space above this line?
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> Why is there vertical space here? and how can I remove it?

It's because the length parameter `\parsep`, which governs the vertical space between paragraphs in a list environment, is non-zero by default. It's a "rubber length" (warning: some TeX jargon is being used), with default value `5.0pt+2.5pt-1.0pt` for level-1 enumerations.

To set this length to zero for a given level of item enumeration, change

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

to

```
\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt]
```

If, on the other hand, you want to set `\parsep` to zero *globally*, for *all* enumeration levels, I suggest you change

```
\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent}
```

to

```
\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent,
                    parsep=0pt
                   }
```

in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way that whitespace is interpreted. I included some options for you, but there are many more ways to accomplish what you've asked.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Imported packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, isbn=false, doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}

% Lemma & Example commands
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}

% Single letter sets
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

% New operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}

% Indentation Settings
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent}

\title{Homework 2 - MATH 4001}
\author{Clyde Kertzer}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        First line.
            
        Why is there vertical space above this line?
        
        \item
        Second line. \\
        Less vertical space.
        
        \item 
        Third line.
        %
        No space.
        
        \item 
        Fourth line. \vspace{-0.5em}
        
        Less space but indented.
        
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```